# Cann't start SQL Server after replacing master.mdf and mastlog.ldf

Tags: sql-server, recovery

As you know, after installing SQL Server, there will be a master db with physical files master.mdf and mastlog.ldf.

I had an old version of MSSQL and there are some testing data in the master db. So I copied the old master files to replace the new ones. Then I can't start the new MSSQL Server any more.

[image]

> The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion.
> Consult the event log or other applicable error logs for details.

I thought, OK, just replacing won't work, I know there is a template / backup for the db files, under `MSSQL\Binn\Templates`, no big deal.

[image]

But after I replacing them with these files under Templates folder, the server still can't start. I realized it's critical.

The data in master db is not important, my question is how to start the server, thanks!

Edit: even repair with the installation didn't work.

[image]

Comment: I guess you need to rebuild the system dbs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/rebuild-system-databases?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Word for the wise, this is one reason that user data shouldn't be stored in the system databases, especially `master`.

Comment: So you just replaced the files for the old `master` database without backing up the original in any way?

Comment: There may be a more useful error message in event viewer.

Comment: Just imagine the boot process. Master points to where the files for model are and tempdb to be created. Of that fails (points to the wrong location) then the boot fails. Event viewer snf possibly errorlog file should have details.

Comment: Also copying over Master is not supported, and if you don't the old and new master databases didn't come from the exact same SQL Server version it may not even work.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-the-master-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: It sounds like you copied the master file from an older instance of SQL Server? I think for this to work, both versions of SQL Server need to match  exactly